# Mapping Through an Array w/ React and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to map JSON from an API call to a return using bootstrap. I want the name to map over one by one to all the columns and rows until all the data has been displayed. Currently, it is mapping all the data(names) in all 3 columns.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API + 'ts=' + date + 'apikey=' + pubKey + 'hash=' + hash)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            char: result.data.results,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }

      )
  }


  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, char } = this.state;
    return (
      char.map(char => 
        <Container>
          <Row>
          <Col md="4"> <h2>{char.name}</h2></Col>
          <Col md="4"> <h2>{char.name}</h2></Col>
          <Col md="4"> <h2>{char.name}</h2></Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: "want the name to map over one by one to all the columns and rows". What do you mean by this?

Comment: It may be helpful to include the JSON result/results array and what properties you want mapped. It's currently unclear what your expected result should be. What do you want mapped "one-by-one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, if you are trying to map through all the data and want to display it inside grid.
You should do the following.

```
render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, char } = this.state;
    return (
        <Container>
          <Row>
           { char.map(char => (<Col md="4"> <h2>{char.name}</h2></Col> ) }
          </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: That seemed to be it. Thank you !! Just curious did you find documentation on this online? I looked forever trying to find a solution but couldn't.

Comment: I just read your mind :P.
I have some experience with the Grid System and the Responsiveness.

Comment: Also do accept the answer so that the other users need not invest their time for finding the correct solution. :)